# LDAP to REST integration

Tags: rest, ldap, middleware, esb

I have server and client which use LDAP to communicate. I have to upgrade server and new version of server supports only REST API. Changing client code to support REST is not possible currently.

Is it possible to convert LDAP requests to REST and vice versa by putting another application between my server and client?

Answer (score 0):

in theory it is possible. It has to implement the LDAP server protocol. It also has to be able to impersonate whatever authentication and encryption your LDAP client expects. Calling REST services is usually easy.

It is not clear what kind of communication is performed. I would expect the LDAP protocol to be used only as its design intended.